# Parse DSML XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a DSML XML being pulled from our intranet that I need to parse to pull the values from. The start of the XML looks like below.
I'm looking at how to get started with pulling off the values such as name, email, etc. The schema and what code I have don't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dsml="http://www.dsml.org/DSML">
- <SOAP-ENV:Body>
- <dsml:dsml xmlns:dsml="http://www.dsml.org/DSML">
- <dsml:directory-entries>
- <dsml:entry dn="ssouid=8dc00fd1-ca9a-1642-c7f6-0003ba128a2e,ou=Worker, o=website.com">
- <dsml:objectclass>
  <dsml:oc-value>top</dsml:oc-value> 
  <dsml:oc-value>person</dsml:oc-value> 
  <dsml:oc-value>organizationalPerson</dsml:oc-value> 
  <dsml:oc-value>inetOrgPerson</dsml:oc-value> 
  <dsml:oc-value>SSOperson</dsml:oc-value> 
  <dsml:oc-value>idmcolab</dsml:oc-value> 
  </dsml:objectclass>
- <dsml:attr name="ssodialcommfax">
  <dsml:value /> 
  </dsml:attr>
- <dsml:attr name="hrindustrygroup">
  <dsml:value>Group Name</dsml:value> 
  </dsml:attr>
- <dsml:attr name="ssoaceid">
  <dsml:value>1234567</dsml:value> 
  </dsml:attr>
- <dsml:attr name="ssoknownas">
  <dsml:value>John</dsml:value> 
  </dsml:attr>
- <dsml:attr name="mail">
  <dsml:value>john.doe@company.com</dsml:value> 
  </dsml:attr>
- <dsml:attr name="uid">
  <dsml:value>1234567</dsml:value> 
  </dsml:attr>
  </dsml:entry>
  </dsml:directory-entries>
  </dsml:dsml>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: `The schema and what code I have don't seem to be working.` Consider to show your code, maybe someone can help you then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
namespace parseXML
{
class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("parse.xml");
XmlNode child; 
int count=doc.GetElementsByTagName("dsml:attr").Count;
for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++)
{
child=doc.GetElementsByTagName("dsml:attr")[i];
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine("dsml:attr>> "+child.Attributes["name"].Value);
Console.WriteLine("dsml:value>> "+child.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
}
Console.ReadKey(true);
}}}
```

Output:

dsml:attr>> ssodialcommfax
dsml:value>>

1
dsml:attr>> hrindustrygroup
dsml:value>> Group Name

2
dsml:attr>> ssoaceid
dsml:value>> 1234567

3
dsml:attr>> ssoknownas
dsml:value>> John

4
dsml:attr>> mail
dsml:value>> john.doe@company.com

5
dsml:attr>> uid
dsml:value>> 1234567

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

İf you didn't copy and paste xml to this issue wrong, the xml is not well formatted please add following lines at the end and than try to parse again;

```
...
</dsml:entry>
</dsml:directory-entries>
</dsml:dsml>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Updated XML to include the footer tags

Comment: Can you parse XML now then?

Comment: No, my code doesn't seem sufficient using: var Email = doc.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://www.dsml.org/DSML") + "mail").First();

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement directory = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "directory-entries").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = directory.Name.Namespace;
            var results = doc.Descendants(ns + "directory-entries").Select(x => new
            {
                dn = (string)x.Element(ns + "entry").Attribute("dn"),
                ocValue = x.Descendants(ns + "oc-value").Select(y => (string)y).ToList(),
                attr = x.Descendants(ns + "attr").Select(y => new {
                    name = (string)y.Attribute("name"),
                    value = (string)y.Element(ns + "value")
                }).ToList()
           }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```